# How to tell to HILT to inject implementation instead of interface, in the constructor

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-hilt

I face to this problem when I try to code some test.

I have a repository class and an interface.

```
class ItemsRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: MercadoLibreApi
): IItemsRepository {
```

```
interface IItemsRepository {
    suspend fun getSearch(search: String): Resource<ResponseML>
}
```

a viewmodel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repo: ItemsRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {
```

and a Retrofit instance that is injected using Dagger/Hilt

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesMercadoLibreApi(retrofit: Retrofit): MercadoLibreApi {
        return retrofit.create(MercadoLibreApi::class.java)
    }
```

In my new MainViewModelTest class I want to create a mockedRepository instance.

```
private lateinit var itemsRepository : MockupItemsRepository
```

from this class:

```
class MockupItemsRepository: IItemsRepository { .. }
```

And then I want to use :

```
@Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MainViewModel(itemsRepository)
    }
```

But I'm getting an error because "itemsRepository" is type MockupsItemsRepository
and then I go to MainViewModel class, and change the parameter:

```
 val repo: IItemsRepository  //I'm using the interface
```

The error in MainViewModelTest dissapear, but I can't compile.

Hilt tells me thta I need a @Provides for the parameter:

> IItemsRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated
> method

How to tell HILT that I want the implementation, not the interface?

Thanks for any idea, I may be doing too much trouble to test one method in the viewmodel ...

Best Regards

Comment: If the interface is IItemsRepository, you should be injecting and storing IItemsRepository in the ViewModel, not ItemsRepository.  You can't store an MockupItemsRepository into it, because MockupItemRepository is an IItemsRepository but not an ItemRepository.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan , yes, I know, thta why I change this line : val repo: IItemsRepository  //I'm using the interface in the viewmodel, but when I try to compile HILT fails...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in this video from Mitch Tabian

https://codingwithmitch.com/courses/hilt-dependency-injection/modules-binds-and-provides/

In AppModule class I had to add the correct provider:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesItemsRepository(api: MercadoLibreApi): IItemsRepository = ItemsRepository(api)
```

I was confused and I was returning class ItemsRepository instead of the interface!

Some additional links:

https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/dagger-2-binds-vs-provides-cbf3c10511b5

Best Regards